# noImplicitAny with object literal in function parameter

Tags: typescript, types, angular9

In `tsconfig.json` I have

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny" true
  }
}
```

I have a function with an object literal parameter like so:

```
public addHandler({ sender }) {
}
```

But VSC gives me an error:

> Binding element 'sender' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Trying `addHandler(sender: any)` breaks the function, and `addHandler({ sender: any })` does not compile.

Can you help me write this code please?

Comment: Setting `"noImplicitAny": true`, but trying to type with `any` ?

Comment: @AlekseyL.I do not get the error with it false at any rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object literal containing `sender` is implicitly `any`. Add a type to that declaration and it should fix it.

`public addHandler({ sender }: any) {}`

Comment: Oops, I thought I tried that.  Thank you.  It works for larger literals too apparently: `{ sender, rowIndex, dataItem }: any`